# IIS7 WebDAV Browsing

Tags: iis-7, webdav

I'm creating Virtual Directories in IIS7 so that external people can browse various documents.

It's all looking good, except the browsing is in a dull text format. How can I create more of a "Windows Explorer" look and feel when they browse to the folder.

Answer (score 1):

If you enable webdav on these folders then the users (with windows computers) can use windows explorer to access these folders just like a folder on their harddrive.
You can map a network drive and use the url as path.
Here is some more explanation [Mapping windows drive](http://barracudaserver.com/products/BarracudaDrive/tutorials/mapping_windows_drive.lsp)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest taking a look at IT Hit's Ajax File Browser: http://www.ajaxfilebrowser.com/

It is a WebDAV client written in pure JavaScript that runs in IE, Firefox, Chrome and Safari. It looks very similar to Windows Explorer and has lots of programming features: http://www.webdavsystem.com/ajaxfilebrowser/programming/